# Will git add -A keep the deleted files on disk?

Tags: git, file

```
touch asdf
git add asdf
git commit -m 'bleh'
rm asdf
git add -A
git commit -m 'bleh'
```

Has the file `asdf` been completely deleted (that is, git doesn't know anything about it and cannot revert to a state where this file existed), or is it still somewhere cached in `.git/`?

**Edit:** If asdf still remains somewhere: is there a command that could permanently delete it in the described way? (This seems impossible as it would pretty much be breaking git IMO.)

Comment: You could just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asdf` will still exist in the commit history. You can still get logs for it, show its contents (from the history), and restore it.

If you want to permanently delete the file from your history, follow the steps in [this help guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

Comment: Hello, I added a sub-question, could you answer it as well? (Or should I start a new question entirely?)